# Find excluded keywords for $_POST/$_GET content in ModSecurity?

Tags: php, apache, security, mod-security

Our client has `ModSecurity 2.0` with `Rule Set 2.0.5` but he told us that *minor detail* at the end of the development.

I need to audit all the application code and make sure it does not interfere with `ModSecurity`. (It already does)

I know that you can't submit forms in `POST` with the key `'content'`, and `'document'` which heavily impacts our application.

**Given the number of version/ruleset of `ModSecurity`, where can I find comprehensible explanation of what I must not use for keys `$_GET` and `$_POST` and/or forbidden headers values ?**

The documentation I found on the website is too generalistic, or maybe I misread it.

Thanks

Comment: Agree that good documentation for this is hard to find. Is it possible to run a list of all your keywords through a trial app - in other words, find forbidden values by trial and error? Alternatively I imagine that if you prepend a small unique character sequence (`Tristan_document`, `Tristan_content` etc) you will be safe. Unsatisfactory, I know.

Comment: Thanks. Well that only cover the part involving form in POST. but what about $_GET / Headers..... that is so disappointing that I have to go fully blinded only by reading apache logs :'(

Comment: You could see if there are people on serverfault.com who can help...